# How to apply a gift certificate to the sales order In NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to apply a gift certificate to the sales order in Netsuite using the suite script. How it can be possible to apply a gift certificate to the sales order?

Comment: Hi Yasir, were you able to find a solution to your question? I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: Here's some notes on how gift certificates work https://mikebian.co/notes-on-netsuites-gift-certificate-record/

Comment: Hi, @NadeemKhoury I applied a gift certificate to the sales order by using the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied a gift certificate to the sales order by using the code below.

```js
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'giftcertfrom',
                        value: 'sender name'
                    });

                    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'giftcertmessage',
                        value: 'sender message'
                    });

                    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'giftcertnumber',
                        value: 'gift card number/code/coupon'
                    });

                    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'giftcertrecipientemail',
                        value: 'recipient email'
                    });

                    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'giftcertrecipientname',
                        value: 'recipient name'
                    });
                    salesOrder.commitLine({
                        sublistId: 'item'
                    });
```